# Boot from usb but keep data partition on hard disk

Tags: linux, linux-mint, usb-drive

I have a company PC equipped with Windows. I need to use Linux (mint) to do some tests.

A Linux virtual machine is too slow for those tests, and a live usb with persistence has very poor performance s.

I am asking if it is possible to keep linux OS partitions inside one or more loopback files hosted by the Winfows NTFS hard drive. Then build a live bootable usb pen with Linux in charge of the boot after mounting the partitions stored in the previous described external windows drive.

Up to Ubuntu 12.04 we had a discontinued project named Wubi. It was able to boot from partitions stored on windows, but with the drawback to replace the windows boot loader (which I cannot do!).

Maybe it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Make a couple of new partitions for linux in your disk (very easy). Install linux to them (moderate, but easy with ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but as I described I have some constraints. I cannot touch the disk, so I would install it on loopback files, and start the OS booting from USB. Is it possible?

Comment: If your computer has USB3 ports, then: Use an ssd connected via USB3 (should be as fast as an installed disk) (around 500MByte/sec, almost the max of a sata2 bus). It could be done with a 20 U$ usb3 to sata2 cable and (here is the expensive) a 60-120U$(depending of size) sata disk. But the disk could be reused in any other computer and to keep a copy of you valuable data.

Comment: Here is the exact case I described  http://www.opopop.net/booting_linux_from_a_loop_file_system/ .

Comment: I could ask what would happen if the NTFS filesystem gets into trouble because an unexpected crash. That would require windows chkdsk to recover. That is not what I would call a robust solution. But what do I know? Live and learn ... ...

Comment: I agree with you about reliability, bit if you read my original post I cannot touch the original disk.